# How would I implement global and local variables in LLVM-C for a c-like language?

Tags: c, llvm

I'm writing a c-like language for fun, and I'm confused with LLVM's C bindings. Is there a function like `LLVMBuildGlobal` that will let me create a local variable? I've never used the C++ LLVM bindings, and I'm currently writing my project in C using the LLVM C API.

Comment: the word you are looking for is `alloca`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Oooh, okay. Just looked that up in the docs and it takes the builder, type, and name. So would the type be the type of the variable, and the name is the name of the variable? How would I assign this a value?

Comment: I guess exactly as you would assign to any other storage? `StoreInst`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Nice, thanks! If you wanna submit this as the answer, then I'll mark it.

Comment: this isn't really worth an answer, it took .5 + .5 minutes of googling.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant right ok